# Unable to make http POST request in java?

Tags: java, http-post

```
static HttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
static HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://servername:6405/biprws/logon/long");
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
          ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters  = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", "Administrator"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "test"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("auth", "secEnterprise"));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
        httppost.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Header s = response.getFirstHeader("logontoken");
        String s1 =  s.getValue();
        System.out.println(s1);// null pointer exception here
    }
```

Running the code above i am not able to add request body to the POST request. How can i achieve this?

Alternative method i followed:

```
HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://servername:6405/biprws/logon/long");
     String json = "{\"UserName\":\"Administrator\",\"Password\":\"test\",\"Auth\":\"secEnterprise\"}";
     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");
     entity.setContentType("application/json");
     post.setEntity(entity);
     System.out.println(entity);
     post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

     HttpResponse response = client1.execute(post);
     BufferedReader rd1 = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));


    String result1 = null;
    String line1 = "";

        result1 =  rd1.readLine();
        System.out.println(result1);
```

Still i am not able to make request.

Answer (score 0):

You are successfully receiving a response which does ***not*** contain the "logontoken" header.  Very possibly because the response is not an HTTP 200 OK response.  Why? We don't know, it all depends on the protocol that your server implements on top of HTTP.

That having been said, the use of both `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFromEntity(postParameters))` and `httppost.addHeder("Content-Type", "application/json")` does not look right to me.  A URL-encoded form entity is not of json content type.  So, either convert your post parameters to json, or lose the content-type header.

Comment: pls check the alternative method i have posted, not able to add request body, How can i achieve this?@ https://stackoverflow.com/users/773113/mike-nakis

Comment: "I am not able to make request" is not a description of a problem.  You need to explain precisely what the problem is.  At the very least, you need to check the response status, and tell us what it was.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized is the status i am getting @Mike Nakis